# Change Tab Link on Click (and Already Active Anchor)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to piece together js knowledge as I go here. But I have a website that will be relying on a tabbed (just 2) concept to flip between the companies two services.

So when navigating to the page, they user will be directed to Company1 and I would like to have a tab of Company 2 on the right. It will be the same domain, just domain.com#company2.

When they navigate to Company 2 directly (via domain.com#company2) I would like the tab on the right to link to Company 1.

So basically, it looks like js is the only way to do this. Something that could read the active id and style the tab accordingly.

The main function would be based on click. So if you click the tab, it switches to the non-active companies tab.

The tab itself will remain the same, all I need to change is the href.

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: are you using a built in `tab` ? something like `Jquery-UI tab` or `bootstrap tab` ? or are you creating you own tab?

Comment: I'm creating my own tab. At the top of my page, I plan on having a 50px or so high div, with the right 30% a link that I need to be changed.

So this is the ROUGH mockup, as it looks horrendous but I'll host it right now so we can see it:
http://spencerford.com/demos/performancegroup/

You can see that clicking each 'tab' takes you to the respective service they offer. My hope is that there will just be one tab on the right (where the 'Performance Group' tab is right now will be blank, the 'Leadership Journey' tab is what changes).

Comment: maybe you should use something like JQUery-UI tab, its much easier. http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: I'm playing around with it right now to see what I can do with it. But maybe I'm misleading my intentions by referencing it as a tab. Really, what I need is a fixed link (that will be styled like a tab, albeit) in the top right that links to another div. And I need that link to reference the non-active div.

It's a 1-page setup, with a 200% width wrapper and 2 divs taking up 100% width. So that link anchors between the 2 divs, but not necessarily a tab switching as I'm implying.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use CSS float :

```
$("#tab1_id").click(function(){
    $(".2tabs_class").css("float","left)
})
$("#tab2_id").click(function(){
    $(".2tabs_class").css("float","right)
})
```

Make sure 2 tabs are inside a div

Comment: Thanks for the answer bud, but I'm not 100% sure on what this does. I'm playing around with it right now and I really can't get it to do anything.

Currently, I'm using:
$("#tab1").click(function(){
    $(".tabbedNav").css("float","left")
})
$("#tab2").click(function(){
    $(".tabbedNav").css("float","right")
})

<div id="headerNav" class="tabbedNav">
  <ul>
    <a href="#Page1">
    <li id="tab1" class="Page1Link">The Performance Group</li>
    </a> <a href="#Page2">
    <li id="tab2" class="Page2Link">The Leadership Journey</li>
    </a>
  </ul>
</div>

Comment: May be I dont understand cleary your question.

The above code help :
-  If you click on tab1 tab1 will on the left, tab2 on the right
-  If you click on tab2 tab2 will on the left, tab1 on the right

Is that what you want ?

And you should post your code so it's easier for people to help you

Comment: Yeah, I've been a mess with this. Thanks for putting up with it. What I was hoping for was for a 'tab' like element on the right to swap. But, you did lead me to something I didn't think of and I've figured it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/Split98/bgwH6/ See how when you click it swaps to the other tab? Perfect. Now, the only last piece I need to figure out (if possible) is for the jQuery to recognize which div is active. So, if they navigate to domain.com by default the tab shown will be to #page2. However, if they directly navigate to domain.com#page2 I will need the visible tab to be #page1